# Deploy Microsoft Node.js bot using Visual Studio

Tags: botframework

I have created Azure Bot service for nodeJS LUIS bot. 
Downloaded the zip file to for local development.

Now I want to publish the changes back to Azure Bot from Visual studio 2017.

Which different environment variables I need to set to publish from desktop without using Visual studio services.

Answer (score 2):

You can setup continuous deployment by following the guidelines in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/azure-bot-service-continuous-deployment#set-up-continuous-deployment).

1. Download your source code via `.zip` file from the Azure Bot Service interface.
2. Upload your code to one of the following source control providers:

   - Visual Studio Team Services
   - OneDrive
   - Local Azure Git Repository
   - GitHub (recommended)
   - Bitbucket
   - Dropbox
   - External Repository

[image: VCS Options]

3. In Azure Bot Service, select "Settings", then go to the section "Continuous deployment" and click the "Configure" button under the section "Step 3: Configure continuous deployment"

[image: Configure continuous deployment]

4. In the "Deployments" blade, click the "Setup" link by the gears icon.
5. In the "Deployment option" blade to the right, click "Choose Source"
6. Select the source control service your selected in step 2 above, for example GitHub
7. Configure your repository-specific settings in the "Deployment option" blade, including project and branch, then click "OK"
8. You should see a popup notification that says "Setting up deployment source"
9. In the "Deployments" blade of your Bot Service, you should see a log of your current deployment.
10. Done!

Now when you push changes to your code repository, it will trigger an automatic redeployment of your bot's code, which you can monitor using the "Deployments" blade.

For more information, check out the complete article on Azure Continuous Deployment here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-continuous-deployment

Answer (score 0):

You can also open the **Advanced settings** in Azure:
[image: advanced settings]

And download the publish profile:
[image: get publish profile]

Then, create a new Visual Studio Node.js project using the "From Existing Node.js code" TypeScript template (selecting the folder that contains the files downloaded):

Visual Studio Node Project Wizard 1:
[image: Visual Studio Node Project Wizard 1]

Visual Studio Node Project Wizard 2:
[image: Visual Studio Node Project Wizard 2]

Finally, import the publish profile downloaded earlier:
[image]

You should now be able to publish directly from Visual Studio.